# Google App Engine servlet not updating when I save?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

Whenever I run Google App Engine it seems to be running an older version of the servlet than the last one I've saved.

What's going on? How can I fix this?

I'm using the GAE Eclipse Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a common pitfall. I also ran into a couple of times.
You should delete the `cookies` and the `cache` from `Chrome`.

If this isn't working, you should `terminate and restart` the server at eclipse all the time, when you modify the server side code.